# the point $z =0$ is choose the correct option

Tags: complex-analysis

for the  function $$f(z) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{\cos\frac{1}{z}}\right)$$, the  point $z =0$ is

choose the correct option

$1)$  removable singularity

$2) $ pole

$3)$ an essential singularity

$4)$ a non-isolated singularity

My attempt : option  4)  will correct  i thinks  its  will have  non-isolated singularity because limit  of singularity  are  $\dfrac{2}{\pi}, \dfrac{2}{3\pi}, \dfrac{2}{5\pi}, \ldots$.

is  its  true  ?

Comment: Correct answer. Indeed $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis thanks'